# Sum of multiple data type columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider:

```
Name   Location code  ID  Details  Column5        Code
Kirsh  HD12           76  Age:25   127.3          Yes
Kirsh  HD12           76  Age:25   12758.56       Yes
Kirsh  HD12           76  Age:25   No data found  No
John   HD12           87  Age:25;  76.45          Yes
John   HD12           87  Age:25;  No data found  No
John   HD12           87  Age:25;                 No
John   HD12           87  Age:25;  16578.56       Yes
Ward   HD12           87  Age:25;                 No
Ward   HD12           87  Age:25;                 No
```

I want this as:

```
Name   Location code  ID  Details  Column5    Code
Kirsh  HD12           76  Age:25   12962.31   Yes
John   HD12           87  Age:25;  16655.01   No
Ward   HD12           87  Age:25;             No
```

Comment: Column5 contains multiple data types(123.45, 123.00, 123.0, 123, data not found)

Comment: Your example is hard to read. can you provide your example code?

Comment: It seems like you want something roughly like; `df.groupby(['Name']).agg({'Location': 'max', 'code': 'max', 'ID': 'max', 'Details': 'sum', 'Column5': 'max'}).reset_index()`

Comment: Why are these work orders answered? What is driving it? Why would someone do somebody else's homework? Is it paid homework? Reputation points harvesting? Spam bots posting questions and answering?

Comment: TAB-separated data ought to be properly formatted to render properly here on Stack Overflow (TABs are replaced by four spaces; they are not on the HTML page), especially when there are ***empty cells*** (in "Column5"). For instance, it could be converted to a [Markdown table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Please replace those "No data found" with either 0 or NaN:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
  "Name": ["Kirsh", "Kirsh", "Kirsh", "John", "John", "John", "John", "Ward", "Ward"],
  "Location": ["HD12", "HD12", "HD12","HD12", "HD12", "HD12", "HD12","HD12", "HD12"],
  "Code": [76, 76, 76, 87, 87, 87,87, 87,87],
    "Id": ["Age:25", "Age:25", "Age:25", "Age:25", "Age:25", "Age:25", "Age:25", "Age:25", "Age:25"],
    "Details":[127.3, 12758.56, np.nan, 76.45, np.nan, np.nan, 16578.56, np.nan, np.nan],
    "Column5": ["Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"]

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Details'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Details'].transform('sum')

gk = df.groupby("Name")
gk.first()
```

Please see *[Python | Pandas dataframe.groupby()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-groupby/)* for groupby information.

Also, please see [the comment of John Stud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74725123/sum-of-multiple-data-type-columns-in-pandas#comment131884786_74725123). He already answered with the best solution.

Comment: This is incorrect. If you look at the original TAB-separated data, then "Column5" contains the numbers, string *"No data found"*, and the empty cells.: *"127.3"*, *"12758.56"*, *"No data found"*, *"76.45"*, *"No data found"*, *""*, and *"16578.56"*. Column "Code" contains "Yes" and "No".

Comment: Re *"Please replace those "No data found" with either 0 or NaN"*: Why? It might be the gist of the question that it should be able to handle that kind of input. There is also an indication in the title: ***"multiple data type columns"***

Comment: yes you are right @Peter Mortensen. Also @ John Stud already gave the answer in comment